# Use SingleDateAndTimePicker in Room database

Tags: android, datetimepicker, android-room

I have this code for the room database...

**ShiftLog.java**

```
@Entity
public class ShiftLog {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_uid")
    private int userUid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "shift_start")
    private SingleDateAndTimePicker shiftStart;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "shift_end")
    private SingleDateAndTimePicker shiftEnd;
```

However, I get the error `Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it`. How do I use a type converter for this custom class? I took the custom class from https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SingleDateAndTimePicker` is a view, and not a piece of data. You therefore don't want to be using that as a property on `ShiftLog`, but instead be using the `Date` that the user would choose using the `SingleDateAndTimePicker`

```
@Entity
public class ShiftLog {
    ...

    @ColumnInfo(name = "shift_start")
    private Date shiftStart;

   ...
```

The date would come from the `SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener` (see the "Usage" section in that library's README for details).

You would still need a `TypeConverter` for the `Date` object as this considered complex data. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) is a tutorial on how to do just that. As a bonus, the example they use in that tutorial is for the `Date` class!

Answer (score 0):

SingleDateAndTimePicker is a UI component, you don't to save it in your DB.

This is a sample from [SingleDateAndTimePicker repository](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker)

```
new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(context)
        //.bottomSheet()
        //.curved()
        //.minutesStep(15)
        //.displayHours(false)
        //.displayMinutes(false)
        //.todayText("aujourd'hui")
        .displayListener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.DisplayListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDisplayed(SingleDateAndTimePicker picker) {
                                 //retrieve the SingleDateAndTimePicker
                            }
                        })

        .title("Simple")
        .listener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(Date date) {

            }
        }).display();
```

You can use a listener to retrieve a **Date** object and save it to your DB instead of the *SingleDateAndTimePicker*.

To manage Date attributes with Room see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)